# Chrome driver is not opening on alpine

Tags: google-chrome, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I am setting up chrome driver using below given command, and when i run it, it gives below given error.

**Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.**

```
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache bash \
    alsa-lib \
    at-spi2-atk \
    atk \
    cairo \
    cups-libs \
    dbus-libs \
    eudev-libs \
    expat \
    flac \
    gdk-pixbuf \
    glib \
    libgcc \
    libjpeg-turbo \
    libpng \
    libwebp \
    libx11 \
    libxcomposite \
    libxdamage \
    libxext \
    libxfixes \
    tzdata \
    libexif \
    udev \
    xvfb \
    zlib-dev \
    chromium \
    chromium-chromedriver
```

Can anyone please help on this?